# How much is the value of the wizard?

Tags: chess-variants, pieces, point-value, unorthodox-pieces

I came up with a new chess piece called the "Wizard".What it does basically is that it can switch places with any piece(except pawns) and for 1 move it has the attributes of the switched piece but cannot move for 1 move.He can deliver check,checkmate etc..For example suppose we have a knight at a5.If the wizard switches places with the knight 19.W=Na5 he will get the attributes of the knight.Then the wizard will continue to act as a Knight and we will be able to use him again on move 21.Oh he remains frozen meaning you cannot move him on move 20.

Also you cannot switch places with a piece under a absolute pin.And the wizard cannot move if he is under a absolute pin.

How much would that piece worth?

Comment: So the wizard can only move as that piece for *one* move?

Answer (score 1):

Considering that the Queen has the combined power of a rook and knight and her value is the combined value of the rook and knight; perhaps the wizard should have the combined value of all pieces since he potentially has the movement capabilities of all pieces?

**Edit:** Considering that a wizard & minor piece cannot mate a lone king, as another user pointed out; perhaps the wizard should have the combined value of all same-coloured pieces *still on the board*?

Comment: Still a king+wizard+bishop cannot give checkmate to a king nor a king+wizard+knight.Wouldnt such a strong piece be able toforce checkmate with a minor piece?